# Sqlite sintax error

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have one problem when I run the code. I have one SQlite database whit some columns, one os this columns (Column CHECK have the value 0 or 1). I check this column to determinate the rows that I want to show in one activity. The value 1 is to Class Hate and value 0 is to Class Love. In this class I'm passing this values in the method that read the database to said to this method the rows that I want to put in the activity, but it dosn't work

I get this error:

**02-12 13:57:18.782      866-866/com.example.lovehate.loveandhate E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "CHECK": syntax error
02-12 13:57:18.792      866-866/com.example.lovehate.loveandhate D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-12 13:57:18.792      866-866/com.example.lovehate.loveandhate W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-12 13:57:18.842      866-866/com.example.lovehate.loveandhate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lovehate.loveandhate/com.example.lovehate.loveandhate.Love}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CHECK": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nombre, imagen, checki FROM lovehateTable WHERE  CHECK=0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CHECK": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nombre, imagen, checki FROM lovehateTable WHERE  CHECK=0
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)**

### DataBase Class

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
//Datos de la tabla
final private static String NAME = "lHate03_db"; //nombre DDBB
final static String TABLE_LOVEHATE = "lovehateTable"; //Nombre de la tabla
//Columnas
final static String ID = "_id";
final static String ITEM = "nombre";
final static String CHECK = "checki";
final static String IMG = "imagen";


//comandos
final static String[] columns = {ID, ITEM, IMG, CHECK};
final private static String CREATE_CMD =

        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOVEHATE + " ("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + IMG + " STRING, "
                + CHECK + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1) ";


final private static Integer VERSION = 1;
final private Context mContext;


//Modos edicion
public static final String C_MODO  = "modo" ;
public static final int C_VISUALIZAR = 551 ;
public static final int C_CREAR = 552 ;
public static final int C_EDITAR = 553 ;


//Constructor
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

//Creación de la base de datos
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //Creamos la base de datos
    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Tabla AMORODIO creada");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CMD);
    //La rellenamos
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    values.put(DataBaseHelper.ITEM, "Vetusta Morla");
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.CHECK, 0);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.IMG, "");
    db.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_LOVEHATE, null, values);
    values.clear();

    values.put(DataBaseHelper.ITEM, "ColdPlay");
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.CHECK, 0);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.IMG, "");
    db.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_LOVEHATE, null, values);
    values.clear();

    values.put(DataBaseHelper.ITEM, "All India Radio");
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.CHECK, 1);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.IMG, "");
    db.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_LOVEHATE, null, values);
    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Datos insertados");
}

//Actualización de la base de datos
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // N/A
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // N/A
}

//Borrando de la base de datos
void deleteDatabase() {
    mContext.deleteDatabase(NAME);
}

//Lectura de la base de datos
public Cursor readArtistas(SQLiteDatabase db, int love) {
    String consulta = "";
    if (love == 1)
    {
        consulta = " CHECK=1 ";
    }
    if (love == 0)
    {
        consulta = " CHECK=0 ";
    }
    return db.query(TABLE_LOVEHATE, columns, consulta, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
}


/**
 * Devuelve cursor con todos las columnas del registro
 */
public Cursor getRegistro(long id) throws SQLException
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query( true, TABLE_LOVEHATE, columns, ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);

    //Nos movemos al primer registro de la consulta
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

/**
 * Inserta los valores en un registro de la tabla
 */
public long insert(ContentValues reg)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.insert(TABLE_LOVEHATE, null, reg);
}

/**
 * Inserta los valores en un registro de la tabla
 */
public long update(ContentValues reg)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    if (reg.containsKey(ID))
    {
        //
        // Obtenemos el id y lo borramos de los valores
        //
        long id = reg.getAsLong(ID);

        reg.remove(ID);

        //
        // Actualizamos el registro con el identificador que hemos extraido
        //
        return db.update(TABLE_LOVEHATE, reg, "_id=" + id, null);
    }
    return db.insert(TABLE_LOVEHATE, null, reg);
}
```

}

LoveClass

public class Love extends ListActivity {

```
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
private Cursor c;

private static final String TAG = "Datos";

public static final String C_MODO  = "modo" ;
public static final int C_VISUALIZAR = 551 ;
public static final int C_CREAR = 552 ;
public static final int C_EDITAR = 553 ;
public static final String C_TIPO = "tipo";
public static final int IS_LOVE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_love);

    // Creamos una nueva DataBase
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //Leemos la BBDD y mostramos la info
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 0);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, c, DataBaseHelper.columns,
            new int[] {R.id._id, R.id.nombre}, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);


    //Añadimos el listener del boton
    final Button boton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent i = new Intent(Love.this, Formulario.class);
            i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_CREAR);
            i.putExtra(C_TIPO, IS_LOVE);
          startActivityForResult(i, C_CREAR);
          }
    }
    );
}

public void editHandler(View v) {
    //get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView id =(TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id._id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Love.this, Formulario.class);

    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_EDITAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, Long.valueOf((String)id.getText()));


    this.startActivityForResult(i, C_EDITAR);
}

public void viewHandler(View v) {
    //get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView id =(TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id._id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Love.this, Formulario.class);

    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_VISUALIZAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, Long.valueOf((String)id.getText()));


    this.startActivityForResult(i, C_VISUALIZAR);
}


//Visualizar un dato en Formulario
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Llamamos a la Actividad Formulario indicando el modo visualización y el identificador del registro
    Intent i = new Intent(Love.this, Formulario.class);
    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_VISUALIZAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, id);

    startActivityForResult(i, C_VISUALIZAR);
}

//CApturamos la respuesta a la creación de registro
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //
    // Nos aseguramos que es la petición que hemos realizado
    //
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case C_CREAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            //Leemos la base de datos y mostramos la informacion
            c=mAdapter.getCursor();
            c=mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 0);
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        case C_EDITAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            //Leemos la base de datos y mostramos la informacion
            c=mAdapter.getCursor();
            c=mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 0);
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_love, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

HateClass

public class Hate extends ListActivity {

```
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
private Cursor c;

private static final String TAG = "Datos";

public static final String C_MODO  = "modo" ;
public static final int C_VISUALIZAR = 551 ;
public static final int C_CREAR = 552 ;
public static final int C_EDITAR = 553 ;
public static final String C_TIPO = "tipo";
public static final int IS_LOVE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hate);
    // Creamos una nueva DataBase
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //Leemos la BBDD y mostramos la info
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 1);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, c, DataBaseHelper.columns,
            new int[] {R.id._id, R.id.nombre}, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);


    //Añadimos el listener del boton
    final Button boton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Hate.this, Formulario.class);
            i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_CREAR);
            i.putExtra(C_TIPO, IS_LOVE);
            startActivityForResult(i, C_CREAR);
            }
        }
    );
}

public void editHandler(View v) {
    //get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView id =(TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id._id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Hate.this, Formulario.class);

    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_EDITAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, Long.valueOf((String)id.getText()));


    this.startActivityForResult(i, C_EDITAR);
}

public void viewHandler(View v) {
    //get the row the clicked button is in
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView id =(TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id._id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Hate.this, Formulario.class);

    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_VISUALIZAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, Long.valueOf((String)id.getText()));


    this.startActivityForResult(i, C_VISUALIZAR);
}

// Close database
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mDbHelper.deleteDatabase();
    super.onDestroy();
}

//Visualizar un dato en Formulario
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Llamamos a la Actividad Formulario indicando el modo visualización y el identificador del registro
    Intent i = new Intent(Hate.this, Formulario.class);
    i.putExtra(C_MODO, C_VISUALIZAR);
    i.putExtra(mDbHelper.ID, id);

    startActivityForResult(i, C_VISUALIZAR);
}

//CApturamos la respuesta a la creación de registro
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //
    // Nos aseguramos que es la petición que hemos realizado
    //
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case C_CREAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                //Leemos la base de datos y mostramos la informacion
            c=mAdapter.getCursor();
            c=mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 1);
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        case C_EDITAR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                //Leemos la base de datos y mostramos la informacion
            c=mAdapter.getCursor();
            c=mDbHelper.readArtistas(db, 1);
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hate, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your column "checki":

```
final static String CHECK = "checki";

 // ...

    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOVEHATE + " ("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + IMG + " STRING, "
            + CHECK + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1) ";
```

But the you refer it as CHECK:

```
//Lectura de la base de datos

public Cursor readArtistas(SQLiteDatabase db, int love) {
    String consulta = "";
    if (love == 1)
    {
        consulta = " CHECK=1 ";
    }
    if (love == 0)
    {
        consulta = " CHECK=0 ";
    }
    return db.query(TABLE_LOVEHATE, columns, consulta, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
}
```

You need to either:

**1** rename your column CHECK (note the brackets)

```
final static String CHECK = "[CHECK]";
```

**Or (better)**

**2** refer it with it's correct name:

```
//Lectura de la base de datos

public Cursor readArtistas(SQLiteDatabase db, int love) {
    String consulta = "";
    if (love == 1)
    {
        consulta = " checki=1 ";
    }
    if (love == 0)
    {
        consulta = " checki=0 ";
    }
    return db.query(TABLE_LOVEHATE, columns, consulta, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: `check` is a SQL keyword and needs to be quoted as `"check"` if used as an identifier. So keeping the column as `checki` is easier.

Comment: Right. Fixed (added the `[]` metacharacters). Thank you, Iaalto, your expertise is always "one step beyond".